# Activity class does not exist in android studio

Tags: android, class, android-studio, android-activity

[image]

I keep getting this error when I try to run my android studio. I tried to copy, paste my previous project bit by bit. After I finished it I got this error. I'm really stuck on this one.

Thanks in advance :D

This is my Activity manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.iussystem">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".TermsOfService"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" />
        <activity android:name=".Registracija" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you rename or move your launcher activity to another package?

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov what do you mean by that, I'm quite new at android studio, so if you could please explain

Comment: Because I copied whole ActivityMain from other project

Comment: Check you ActivityMain class package

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov my ActivityMain package is set to the project's package

Comment: And its location must be `com/example/iusystem/MainActivity.java`

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov It is already there but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please share your AndroidManifest.xml. And check your run configuration from menu    Run -> Edit Configurations

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov I posted my manifest

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you are saying your app is in `com/example/iusystem/MainActivity.java`, isnt that a typo?

Either change your package:

```
 package="com.example.iussystem"
```

to

```
 package="com.example.iusystem"
```

Or move your activity the other way.

Comment: The correct package is package="com.example.iussystem", but still it displays the same error

Comment: Add your activity to the question, or a screenshot of your package structure in AndroidStudio

Comment: In the end, I just opened a new project, copied, pasted and it worked. It seems the name was the issue. Anywho thank you all for help <3